# How to select US International as keyboard layout?

Tags: release-hera, keyboard-layout

How do I select English International as my keyboard layout? It does not appear in `System Settings > Keyboard` when I click on `+`:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a submenu in the keyboard layout selection for `English (US)` which I missed. So the steps are as easy as:

1. Go to `System Settings > Keyboard`
2. Click `+` in the lower left corner
3. Select `English (US)` from the list of keyboard layouts
4. Select `English (US, alt. intl.)`
5. Click `Add Layout`